# How to solve Late-enabling CheckJNI?

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I am new in android and I am using genymotion emulator, but suddenly i an getting Late-Enabling Check problem in log cat and my app crashed. I try to run it on other emulator but still got the same message in log cat. I search many site but still cant get proper way to solve it.  Any help is appreciated.

Here is my logcat:

> 08-22 02:24:26.639    1323-1323/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ CheckJNI is OFF
>   08-22 02:24:29.803    1388-1388/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ CheckJNI is OFF
>   08-22 02:24:30.343    1418-1418/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI

Comment: It enables some assertion checkers. You should solve the actual crash, not just trying to turn it off.

Comment: after long hour, I figure out the problem in my drawable folder ,actual source of error. I modified some png's , clean and rebuild project. It works. Thank you for reply.

Comment: @RiteshBhagat If you still remember the details, please post your solution as an answer and mark the question solved. Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

I also faced this problem. Now I am resolved it.

1. Just go to Build tab on the top of andorid studio.
2. then click on Build apk. then run that apk in your device it works and not take much time.

Thank you